# Prevent button in reused cells to appear again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
 @objc func addinterestserver(_ sender: UIButton) {

                                        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                                        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
                                        sender.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Added", comment: ""), for: .normal)
                                        sender.isEnabled = false
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SearchInterestsCustom

        let release = arrayOfRels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.user.text = release.title
        cell.match.text = release.count + NSLocalizedString(" people added", comment: "")
        cell.addbutton.tag = release.eventID
        cell.addbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SearchInterests.addinterestserver), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.addbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        return cell
    }
```

After user tapped the button, It affects also other cell's button, clearly I see same modified buttons several times upon scroll.

How to avoid this?

Comment: In `cellForRowAt` set your button properties back to your desired values.  You need to store the state of a button in your model and use that to set up your button when a reused cell is dequeued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid this by

```
var allSelected = [Int]()
```

//

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SearchInterestsCustom

   if allSelected.contains(release.eventID) {
       cell.addbutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       cell.addbutton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
       cell.addbutton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Added", comment: ""), for: .normal)
       cell.addbutton.isEnabled = false
   }
   else {
         // set default values 


   }

 }
```

//

```
 @objc func addinterestserver(_ sender: UIButton) {

       sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
       sender.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Added", comment: ""), for: .normal)   
       sender.isEnabled = false

       allSelected.append(sender.tag) // store it here 
}
```